# Memory Leak - Windows Services

Tags: memory-leaks

I'm having an odd issue.  When I start up my computer the memory usage in Task Manager steadily increases until my computer becomes unresponsive.

If I go into MSConfig, nothing is checked under the Startup tab.

If I change the Startup Selection to Selective and uncheck Load system services and uncheck Load startup items, reboot, the computer acts properly (no memory leak).  I think startup any services that were set to Automatic.  Still no memory leak.

When I go back to the original startup mode (Normal), and watch task manager with the memory leak, no processes are showing as increasing memory (working set or private working set).  I'm also showing all processes from all users.

So, does anyone have suggestions on how to track down this issue?

FYI...I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Process Explorer from SysInternals.com should allow you to track the memory usage, plotted over a few minutes. I've used this method to trace a memory leak in a NIC driver.

Comment: When looking at processes in taskmanager, be sure to enable show processes form all users

Comment: The first step is you have to disable all services and startup programs you have added yourself. Once you are in a clean boot, and nothing except the required stuff is running, then and only then can you determine what causes the memory leak.  So determine which programs are set to start, and through a process of trial and error, determine which program you installed caused the problem.

Comment: @RandolphWest What am I looking at for Process Explorer?  When I looked before the memory options (working set) mirrored Task Manager.  Is there a way to get a more detailed breakdown?

Comment: Since it's a spelunking exercise, you're going to be looking at as much as you can, and plotting these over time to see which process is using more and more resources. Enable whatever you can in the Process Memory tab, and also look into the Process Performance tab. If it's a service that's causing the leak, you may have to monitor each of the svchost.exe processes, on the Threads tab.

Comment: Any progress?​​

Answer (score 0):

since Poolmon.exe is not available for Windows 7, I use Kernel Pool Monitor, this is an open source tool that you can find easily.

From there, you need to look for the tag that is causing the memory leak.
Open your command promp and move to your drivers folder... usually at %systemRoot%\system32\Drivers

There, you should try to find the tag with the command findstr.
More info about it [findstr link](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb490907.aspx)